# Unexpected result with jodatime LocalDate.now()

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm using [Jodatime for android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) and got this :

```
LocalDate.now() //returns 2015-12-17, which is today
new LocalDate(LocalDate.now().toDate().getTime()); //returns 2015-12-16, which is yesterday
```

That's really unexpected !

Is that

- a misundestanding of mine ?
- a bug of jodatime or joda for android ?
- a problem of localeZone ? (I've been playing with them for a while, but that didn't change anything)

I store dates in my database as long and create them later, there doesn't seem to be any problem though.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate() gives some pointers

Comment: Hmmm I thought so... But then how can I store my dates as long using jodatime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer, in the app method where you call init, you just have to write one more line :

```
JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));
```

This way you set the default of jodatime to the default of your smartphone.

I'm really surprised this cannot be found anywhere.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand why your original code produces the output it does...

Comment: @mcwise That's because jodatime `DateTimeZone.getDefault()` always return UTC.  You want to set it to your actual timezone.

Answer (score 0):

[This part](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate()) is specifying that point.

> Get the date time as a java.util.Date. The Date object created has
>   exactly the same year, month and day as this date. The time will be
>   set to the earliest valid time for that date.
>
> Converting to a JDK Date is full of complications as the JDK Date
>   constructor doesn't behave as you might expect around DST transitions.
>   This method works by taking a first guess and then adjusting the JDK
>   date until it has the earliest valid instant. This also handles the
>   situation where the JDK time zone data differs from the Joda-Time time
>   zone data.

And for your question(how can I store my dates as long using jodatime ? ), you can use miliseconds to store your date as long.

Try like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTime local = new DateTime();
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

    System.out.println("local zone = " + local.getZone());
    System.out.println("  utc zone = " + utc.getZone());

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime();
    System.out.println(" local: " + format.print(local));
    System.out.println("   utc: " + format.print(utc));
    System.out.println("millis: " + utc.getMillis());
}
```

And the output is;

```
local zone = America/Caracas
  utc zone = UTC
 local: 18.Ara.2015 05:06:00
   utc: 18.Ara.2015 09:36:00
millis: 1450431360816
```